# Program for monitoring hard disk usage?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive

Is there a program that allows me to identify which process is using my hard disk the most? And kill it?

It's just that, sometimes, out of nowhere my hard disk starts to being busy with something, like it's defragmenting, and this slows down my programs to a crawl, and I'd like to avoid this, or at least, understand what's happening.

Comment: use your task manager to see whats running.  Anything that would cause this would be a process.

Comment: Try typing perfmon.exe into the run dialog you get your drive performance. @NomenNescio

Answer (score 0):

Diskmon from sysinternals can help you with this. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646